# android studio дизайнер графического интерфейса

Tags: android-studio

Как можно ускорить или оптимизировать работу графического дизайнера интерфейса android studio? Написание программы заняло 10 минут а студия мешает сделать интерфейс полтора часа раскидывая элементы хаотично и постоянно лагая.

Comment: это проблема студии, решить ее не всегда получается, какая у вас версия, покажите разметку

Comment: наиболее вероятна ситуация, что это вы делаете что то неправильно/не понимаете, как работает этот инструмент, чем "коварная" студия мешает вам работать. за все время использования графического дизайнера, я не припомню случая, чтобы он что то куда то раскидывал против моего желания. А вот некоторые лаги - что есть, то есть, приходится мириться. Как бы там есть и текстовый режим, куда сама студия вообще никак не лезет, если вы все же уверены, что виноват инструмент, а не "мастер", который им работает